# Numpy return array of index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Probably this is a dummy question! But I simply can't find the answer!

For the following array `np.arange(-3,3,1.2)` I get this:

```
array([-3. , -1.8, -0.6,  0.6,  1.8])
```

and for this I want to get an index array like the following:

```
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Surely you're not just looking for `np.arange(5)`. So can you clarify the problem?

Comment: What do you want to do with the index?

Comment: If you want to get the indices to that particular array (so that the lengths match), you could use `np.arange(len(np.arange(-3, 3, 1.2)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
a = np.array([-3. , -1.8, -0.6,  0.6,  1.8])
indices = np.arange(a.shape[0])
```

Comment: @npires Don't hesitate to upvote the answer if you liked it (you can do it since you have >= 15 reputation)